# Pandas Matrix Addition/Division between index values and column header values

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have the following the data frame and I want to add the index value plus the column header and divide by 2.

The initial grid would like this:

```
grid = pd.DataFrame(
                   columns=[1,2,3,4,5],
                   index = [1,2,3,4,5]
                  )
grid
```

This results in the following:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

What I'm looking to get is: For example, index of 1 + column header of 3 results in 4, which divided by 2 is 2

```
    1   2   3   4   5
1   1   1.5 2   2.5 3
2   1.5 2   2.5 3   3.5
3   2   2.5 3   3.5 4
4   2.5 3   3.5 4   4.5
5   3   3.5 4   4.5 5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use broadcasting here:

```
grid[:] = (grid.index.values[:,None] + grid.columns.values)/2
```